# don't detect persistence.xml en mac m1

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, macos

> don't detect persistence.xml en Mac m1.
>
> output: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units

```
try {if(emf ==null) {
        
        emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("estudiante");
        System.out.println("conectado!");
    }
        
    }
    catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("Error en la conexion.... "+ e);}
    
    
    return emf.createEntityManager();
```

https://github.com/profermarquez/jpahibernatepostgresqlnetbeansmacos.git

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro ya que indica que el problema esta en tu archivo **`*.xml`** así que debes asegurarte que contenga algo como esto:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
 <persistence-unit name="estudiante">
 <class>es.example.estudiante</class>
 <properties>
 <property name= "hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.nombre" value="nombre" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.apellido" value="apellido" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.direccion" value="direccion" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.id" value="id" />
 </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: No porque no detecta directamente, en mi Mac, el mismo código con la misma estructura de directorios funciona en windows.